# Doubts in the strcpy function used

Tags: c, string

I am using two buffers which are of `unsigned char` and when I used the function `strcpy`, there is a compilation error which says "invalid conversion of unsigned char * to char *". Can anyone please tell me what difference does an unsigned buffer vs. signed buffer makes to the output?  This is the program which I had tried.

```
        main()
        {
                unsigned char buff[20] = "Michael";
                unsigned char dst[20] = "Jackson";
                strcpy(buff,dst);
                printf("The string is %s\n",buff);

        }
```

Now when i typecast the parametrs passed in strcpy to (char *),This programe works fine as shown below

```
        main()
        {
                unsigned char buff[20] = "Michael";
                unsigned char dst[20] = "Jackson";
                strcpy((char *)buff,(char *)dst);
                printf("The string is %s\n",buff);

        }
```

2nd Question: Does typecasting to char* in the string function create any issues?

Please do let me know if you need any more inputs.

Comment: @Yahia agreed: Maddy, you have several outstanding questions that no answer has been accepted for; did they really not answer your question or are you just unfamiliar with how it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just change:

```
unsigned char buff[20] = "Michael";
unsigned char dst[20] = "Jackson";
```

to

```
char buff[20] = "Michael";
char dst[20] = "Jackson";
```

To think of it logically, A string cannot be signed or unsigned, it is not a numeric value to be treated that way, it is just an char array and you should declare and use it so.

***Why do you get the error?***
`strcpy` has the prototype:

```
char *strcpy(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);
```

And what you are passing to it is, `unsigned char*`, when a function is called parameter type checking takes place and the compiler finds that you are not calling the function with proper type parameters and hence it complains about it, When you apply a cast the function arguments match and hence compilation passes.

***Does typecasting to char*** in the string function create any issues?*
No, in this case it doesn't.
Though it makes more sense to change your usage of `unsigned char` for the reasons mentioned above in the answer.

**Suggestion:**
`Strcpy` is not safe, so you are much better off using `strncpy`, it allows you to explicitly specify how many characters to copy, rather than rely on null terminator of the source string, Also this helps avoiding buffer overflow since you explicitly specify a length.

Comment: @Als..Yes i had changed that and it worked fine.But i would like to know the reason why unsigned char arrays cant be used?

Comment: Well, I think just because that is the way it's defined. unsigned char and char are two different types, and a string literal like "Hello World" is an array of char, not unsigned char. The strcpy function (and strlen, strncpy, etc.) expect char*, not unsigned*.

Comment: @Als...Does typecasting to void * create any issues?

Comment: @Maddy: Not in general, `void *` can point to any datatype & that is the very purpose of it, but again it depends on how you are using it.

Comment: I think you are incorrect about strncpy, it [does not](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) add on a null terminus.

Comment: @Als...The reason i asked about typecasting to void * was that i had to run the Quality analysis check for my code and there was an integration of the legacy cod and our code and in the legacy code they were using all the buffers as signed but in our code we used unsigned,so the Quality analysis check tool always gave error on that.Typecasting to char * also didnt clear out those errors.But when i typecased to void * cleared all the errors for strcpy,sprintf,

Comment: @Maddy: I would advice to be careful with typecasting because it is compilers job to complain about incompatible types(there might be loss of data & the they cannot be just used in place of other) but once you use casting all bets are off and you become the one to ensure there is no funny  business, Unless you show the code it is difficult to speculate, Since `unsigned char*` to `char *` should and works as we see in this very example.

Comment: You have a typo: `strcnpy` rather than `strncpy`.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected it, Please feel free to modify such typos or even add significant details that you might feel improve answers, it is allowed, since it SO is a community driven effort. :)

Comment: `strncpy` is _not_ safer than `strcpy`. It has a nasty habit of giving you something that _isn't_ a C string (ie, not null-terminated). The next time you try to do something stringy with it (like strcmp or strlen), you will hit undefined behaviour territory.

Answer (score 6):

The way you are using it should be fine.

But you shouldn't use `unsigned char` arrays with string handling functions. In C strings are char arrays, not unsigned char arrays. Since passing to `strcpy` discards the `unsigned` qualifier, the compiler warns.

As a general rule, don't make things unsigned when you don't have to.

Comment: @cnicutar...The compiler throws an error instead of a warning.The error is "invalid conversion of unsigned cchar * to signed char *.So Its better to use always signed char  arrays instead of unsigned char arrays?

Comment: @Maddy What compiler is that. A C compiler **shouldn't do it**.

Comment: @Maddy Omitting "unsigned" doesn't mean "signed" ;)

Comment: @cnicutar...I was using DEV C++ compiler.But as far as i know,declaring a arras as char buff[20] means signed array right?

Comment: @Maddy Wrong. You should be using a C compiler (C++ is not a superset of C). And wrong again, `char` does not imply "signed".

Comment: @cnicutar..So what does char buff[20]  means..is it signed or unsigned?

Comment: @Maddy "Maybe signed, maybe unsigned, depending on the compiler". **You should be concentrating on using a C compiler** (maybe also reading a book). Just saying.

Comment: @cnicutar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2709/discussion-between-maddy-and-cnicutar)

Comment: @cnicutar..Thnks for the inputs

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` wants `char *`'s, plain and simple.  Cast your buffers to `char *`'s and you'll be fine.  Then there's the whole safety problem with using `strcpy` in the first place...